# MySQL 8 not using Spatial Index?

Tags: mysql, index, spatial, mysql-8.0

I have an issue where whatever I do I cannot get MySQL to use a spatial index.

A query like the following then takes 5 seconds!

Any way to force this to use the index at all?

```
WITH ranked_reports AS (
    SELECT
        station_id,
        raw_text,
        observation_time,
        RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY station_id ORDER BY observation_time DESC ) order_rank 
    FROM
        METAR 
    WHERE
        ST_Distance_Sphere (
            geo_point,
        ST_GeomFromText ( 'POINT(51.85 -0.79)', 4326 )) <= 100 * 1609.34 
    ) SELECT
    * 
FROM
    ranked_reports 
WHERE order_rank =1
```

Explain of query

```
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref   | rows   | filtered | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | NULL       | ref  | <auto_key0>   | <auto_key0> | 8       | const |     10 |   100.00 | NULL                        |
|  2 | DERIVED     | METAR      | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL        | NULL    | NULL  | 585814 |   100.00 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-----------------------------+
```

Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE `METAR` (
  `station_id` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `station_iata` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `observation_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `latitude` float(255,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` float(255,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `raw_text` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `temp_c` float(255,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dewpoint_c` float(255,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wind_dir_degrees` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wind_speed_kt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wind_gust_kt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `visibility_statute_mi` float(255,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `altim_in_hg` float(255,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `altim_in_hPa` float(255,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sea_level_pressure_mb` float(255,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wx_string` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sky_condition` mediumtext,
  `flight_category` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `three_hr_pressure_tendency_mb` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `maxT_c` float(255,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `minT_c` float(255,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `maxT24hr_c` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `minT24hr_c` float(255,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `precip_in` float(255,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pcp3hr_in` float(255,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pcp6hr_in` float(255,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pcp24hr_in` float(255,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `snow_in` float(255,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vert_vis_ft` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_added` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `geo_point` point NOT NULL /*!80003 SRID 4326 */,
  PRIMARY KEY (`station_id`,`observation_time`),
  KEY `IDX_Station` (`station_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `IDX_Deletion` (`observation_time`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `IDX_IATA` (`station_iata`,`observation_time`) USING BTREE,
  SPATIAL KEY `IDX_Spatial` (`geo_point`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't know anything about MySQL's spatial functionality so I can't answer the question, but could you please take a look at this [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530) to see why the posting of images of text to StackExchange is not a good idea?

Comment: @Vérace good point, done

Comment: what if you use `geo_point` point NOT NULL SRID 4326 when creating table?

Comment: It was created that way already.  Also verified using `SELECT DISTINCT ST_SRID(geo_point)from METAR; `

Comment: how many rows does the table contain and how many of them meet the conditions?

Comment: It is above... 585814 rows and 10 from that

Comment: I mean without order_rank = 1, only with ST_Distance_Sphere <= 100 * 1609.34

Answer (score 2):

You need to add SRID to column definition:

> The SRID attribute makes a spatial column SRID-restricted, which has
> these implications:
>
> The column can contain only values with the given SRID. Attempts to
> insert values with a different SRID produce an error.
>
> The optimizer can use SPATIAL indexes on the column. See Section
> 8.3.3, “SPATIAL Index Optimization”.
>
> Spatial columns with no SRID attribute are not SRID-restricted and
> accept values with any SRID. However, the optimizer cannot use SPATIAL
> indexes on them until the column definition is modified to include an
> SRID attribute, which may require that the column contents first be
> modified so that all values have the same SRID.

Comment: The column `geo_point` does have a SRID set.  4326 in fact.  `/*!80003 SRID 4326 */`

Answer (score 2):

Your query has

```
WHERE
    ST_Distance_Sphere (
        geo_point,
    ST_GeomFromText ( 'POINT(51.85 -0.79)', 4326 )) <= 100 * 1609.34 
)
```

In MySQL you must use the [**MBR** functions to use the index.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-relation-functions-mbr.html)

So don't use `ST_Distance_Sphere` instead,

```
MBRContains( ST_Buffer( ST_SRID(POINT(51.85 -0.79), 4326), 100 * 1609.34), geog )
```

Comment: st_buffer(POINT, ...) has not been implemented for geographic spatial reference systems. MySQL does not support ST_BUFFER on SRID other than 0. Future versions will probably change that though.

Answer (score 0):

When comparing return values from spatial functions in where clause, MySQL just ignores the index. This bug is reported in https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76384, and confirmed in my local env with 8.0.27.

Your goal in the question can be translated into another one: Search for points which are within RADIUS unit distance from the given point (LNG, LAT). This can be done by [`ST_Contains/ST_Within`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-contains).

Since `ST_Contains/ST_Within` returns 1 or 0, it’s ok to ignore  `= 1` in the where clause which will only select values with 1. The where clause should be something like:

```
WHERE ST_Contains(
  ST_Buffer(ST_SRID(Point(LNG, LAT), 4326), RADIUS),
  geo_point
)
```